# Apply an equation to each value of an associative array with out using foreach In PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array in PHP.
For example

```
$array= [
  1  => 3000,
  5  => 1250,
  10 => 2000,
  15 => 700,
  17 => 800,
  21 => 1700,
  26 => 4500,
  30 => 200              
];
```

For each values in array which are grater than 1000, I need to do this equation

```
$temp = ($value - 1000) * 2.5
```

And need to get the sum of temp.

I know I can simply write

```
$amount = 0;
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if($value > 1000){
        $amount = $amount + ($value-(1000))*2.5;
    }
}
```

But is their any alternative method? Can I avoid the foreach by using some array function instead ?

Comment: `array_map` may help

Comment: `Can I avoid the foreach by using some array function instead?` Any advantage over simple foreach?

Comment: Even [internal implementation](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-5.3/ext/standard/array.c#L4227) uses a loop. So no advantage over a simple for loop.

Comment: I will go with `foreach()` as well

Comment: @vivek_23 I was practising to answer some interview questions , and Avoid the foreach is something specifically instructed in that question.

Comment: @AnantSingh---AlivetoDie  I was practising to answer some interview questions , and Avoid the foreach is something specifically instructed in that question

Comment: @Sangeetha Fair enough. We didn't knew this till the time you mentioned. Maybe the interviewer wanted to know whether you know any built in functions or not. But, performance wise, a simple foreach would be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [`array_sum`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) as

```
$res = array_map(function ($e) { return ($e > 1000) ? ($e-1000)*2.5 : 0;}, $array);
echo array_sum($res);
```

Live example: [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/Zt6pN)

Answer (score 2):

You can combine 2 **php** functions `array_map` and `array_sum` to get sum of array elements

```
<?php

$array= [
  1  => 3000,
  5  => 1250,
  10 => 2000,
  15 => 700,
  17 => 800,
  21 => 1700,
  26 => 4500,
  30 => 200              
];

$amount = array_sum(array_map(function($value) {
    if( $value > 1000) {
        return ($value-1000)*2.5;    
    } else {
        return 0;
    }

}, $array));

var_dump($amount);
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/acd2b549f308a58ced6e1f5c009b1a8ede25b0db

Answer (score 1):

```
echo array_reduce(
    $array, 
    function ($t, $v) { 
        if ($v > 1000) { 
            $t += 2.5 * ($v - 1000); 
        } 

        return $t; 
    }, 
    0
);
```